# typeORM + mysql doesn't work after "n" requests

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using `typeORM + mysql + express + Typescript`. I have a problem with `typeORM` I wrote a code to find a user in my Mysql database.

Everything worked as well **up to 5 or 6 times**, Then `typeORM` doesn't work. I mean it can't find the user **(My request sometimes is pending for 10 minutes)**

I opened an issue in Github and attached a video. You can see that here:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/10239

**index.ts**

```js
import app from './app';
import '@env';
import { Category, Customer, Inventory, InventoryLocation, Item, Location, Organization, Stock, Supplier, Order, User, LoginHistory, ForgetPassword } from '@src/entity';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    name: 'default',
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    synchronize: false,
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    connectTimeout: 10000,
    logging: false,
    subscribers: [],
    entities: [
        User,
        ForgetPassword,
        Order,
        Category,
        Customer,
        Inventory,
        LoginHistory,
        Item,
        Location,
        Organization,
        Stock,
        InventoryLocation,
        Supplier
    ]
});

AppDataSource
    .initialize()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'Connected to database successfully!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', err.message);
    });

// Start application
const appUrl = new URL(process.env.APP_URL ?? '');
const PORT = Number(appUrl.port || 5000);
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.clear();
    console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', `\nServer running at ${appUrl.href}`);
});
```

**app.ts**

```js
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import {
    authRouter,
} from './routes';
import ServerResponse from './classes/ServerResponse';

const app = express();

// Global middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.use('...', authRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send(ServerResponse.error('ERR_NOT_FOUND'));
    return;
});

export default app;
```

**Find a user**

```js
import User from '@src/entity/User';

const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
        id: user_id,
    },
    select: [
        'id',
        'organization_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'email',
    ],
});
```

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Widnows 11 |
| Node.js version | 18.17.0 |
| Typescript version | 5.1.3 |
| TypeORM version | 0.3.17 |